# Radio button not getting checked after button event

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, radio-button

I have this weird bug in my app, I have four radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="chkWorkOrderStatus" id="chkOK" runat="server" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="chkWorkOrderStatus" id="chkNcUseAsIs" runat="server" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" name="chkWorkOrderStatus" id="chkNcRework" runat="server" value="3" />
<input type="radio" name="chkWorkOrderStatus" id="chkNcAndStop" runat="server" value="4" />
```

Fetching the data from database works fine, but after doing button save event:

```
  public void checkForAsBuiltData(int asBuiltOperationId)
    {
        if (asBuiltOperationId != 0)
        {
            DataSet ds = Assembly.GetAsBuiltData(asBuiltOperationId);
            if (ds != null)
            {
                string status = "", nctext = "";
                status = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Status"].ToString();
                nctext = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["NCText"].ToString();
                if (status != string.Empty)
                {
                    if (status.Equals("1"))
                    {
                        chkOK.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else if (status.Equals("2"))
                    {
                        chkNcUseAsIs.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else if (status.Equals("3"))
                    {
                        chkNcRework.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else if (status.Equals("4"))
                    {
                        chkNcAndStop.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
                if (nctext != string.Empty)
                {
                    txtNonConfText.Value = nctext;
                }
            }
        }        
    }
```

Although when I hover over at breakpoint the checked state says true, when controls are rendered on the screen none of them are checked, although before the save button is clicked at least one of them is selected.

I also noticed when I am doing for example one of those checkbox checked equals true in page load event the checkbox is getting checked.

What am I doing wrong? For some reason the checked event is reset after that button event.

Comment: On your event, the page is posting back and loading again. So, it goes back to initial state where none of the radio was checked. If you check one in page load, that thing happens at time of your page load (hence your event), and you get one radio checked.

Comment: Once a button is clicked and the page is posted back, is previous selected status of a radio button gone? Could you post the button's click event?

Comment: What if you created an asp hiddenfield, then created a onclick subroutine serverside to change the value of the hiddenfield when the radio button is clicked? You could reference the hidden field just once to get the value instead of looping through your radio buttons. But in the end I think your problem might be that the selected option is clearing itself too early in the page lifecycle. Check the radiobutton values in the page_init and see if you get the same result.

Comment: Remember that after this method is executed, the Page_Load will be triggered. Make sure you have the `Page_Load` code inside of `if (!IsPostback)`, so that this will not re-load the checkboxes to an unwanted state.